# Importing geometry data into MySQL using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, geometry, load-data-infile, wkb

I am trying to import CSV data into MySQL using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` syntax. This is normally a fairly simple task, but in this case the data includes a geometry field that is tripping me up.

When I try to run the import, I'm getting errors like this:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4079 Illegal parameter data type longblob for operation 'st_geometryfromwkb'

The records in my CSV file look like this:

```
'Somewhere', -0.574823, 51.150771, '0x0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F0BF'
```

So I have a location name, lat/long coords and a geometry field in binary WKB format. (the example above is a simple geometry that translates to `POINT(1,1)`; the real data has complex polygons, but the content isn't relevant; the issue is the same with this simple example).

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mapping` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `location` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `geom` geometry NOT NULL,
  INDEX mapping_by_location (location),
  SPATIAL KEY `mapping_by_geom` (`geom`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And my import query looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `mapping`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4)
SET
`location` = @col1,
`latitude` = @col2,
`longitude` = @col3,
`geom` = GeomFromWKB(@col4);
```

As stated, with this import query, I am getting the `Illegal parameter data type` error shown at the top of this question.

However, the query works if I replace the final line with a hard-coded geometry string, like this:

```
`geom` = GeomFromWKB(0x0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F0BF);
```

Obviously this isn't any good, as I need the field to load from the CVS not a hard-coded value in the query, but it does work, whereas loading the same value from the CSV in `@col4` does not.

I have tried a bunch of variations on this query - with and without the call to `GeomFromWKB()`, with both `X'...'` and `0x...` notations for the hex value; nothing seems to work.

Can anyone give me some help please?

Comment: have you tried  importing col4 as a string an a temp table and after insert select with cast to geomWKB??  or use WKT on  text geom?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have not tried that. I'll give it a go (although the temp table idea sounds excessively complex; I'll be disappointed if I have to jump through that many hoops just to pull in this data)

Comment: You could also  Try exporting for a test table the equivalent info as csv a data sample and check for difference between the dato in you file and the data managed by mysql

Comment: not sure but it can be the ' ' around the wkb data

Comment: @DanielE. thanks for the comment. I have tried it without the quotes; no difference.

Comment: Other suggestion : Are you sure you don't need to put the SRID, like this : GeomFromWKB(@col4, SRID) ? Because in the documentation, i found this line : "Constructs a Point value using its WKB representation and SRID.

The result is NULL if the WKB or SRID argument is NULL."